# Proof that a minimum problem has no solution

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, calculus-of-variations, functional-calculus

Please I have an exam in a few days, can you help me with the following exercise?

Let $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2: 1<|x|<2\}$ and $M\geqslant 0$.

On the set $\mathcal{A}_{M}=\{u\in C(\bar{A})\cap C^1(A):u=0 \text{ on } |x| \text{ and } u=M \text{ on } |x|=1\}$ consider the area functional:
\begin{equation*}
F:\mathcal{A}_{M}\to[0,\infty]
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
F(u)=\int_A\sqrt{1+|\nabla u(x)|^{2}} \, dx
\end{equation*}

I have to prove the following statement:

3) There exists $M_0$ such that for $M>M_0$ the minimum problem has no solution in the class $\mathcal{A}_M$

Solution: I've computed the Euler Lagrange equation in the strong form for the functional:
\begin{equation*}
F(\phi)= 2\pi\int_1^2 \sqrt{1+\phi'(r)}rdr
\end{equation*}
Obtained from the previous one using the fact that $u$ is radial and computing a change of variables with polar coordinates.

The explicit solution of the strong form of the Euler Lagrange equation is:

\begin{equation*}
\phi(r)=\phi(1)-\int_1^r \dfrac{C}{\sqrt{t^2-C^2}}=M-\log\bigg({\dfrac{x+\sqrt{x^2-C^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-C^2}}}\bigg)
\end{equation*}

$C$ is a real constant.

Can someone help me to find an appropriate concusion of this proof?

Comment: $\lvert X\rvert$ is the distance of the point $X=(x,y)$ from the origin?

Comment: Yes it is the norm:$ |X|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for $X=(x,y)$

Comment: "[...] probably the key is to prove that the functional F is invariant under rotation in the argument of u." That is correct. Do you know how to do that? And do you know how to proceed from there?

Comment: No I do not have any ideas on how to use this fact

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: If $O$ is an orthogonal $2\times 2$ matrix, then $F(u\circ O)=F(u)$. What does that tell us if $u$ is a minimizer? How can you use uniqueness of minimizers now?

Comment: Why is the statement $F(u\circ O)=F(u)$ true? How can we prove it?

Comment: Use the chain rule for the derivative and the change of variables formula for the integral.

Comment: can you please tell me only if it is correct

Answer (score 3):

You're 95% there! You have successfully shown the following:

1. If a minimizer exists, it is unique
2. The area functional $F$ is rotationally invariant

Suppose that $u$ is a minimizer. Then, because $F$ is rotationally invariant, for any $O\in SO(2)$ the function $u\circ O$ is *also* a minimizer. By uniqueness, $u= u\circ O$ for all $O\in SO(2)$, i.e., $u$ is rotationally invariant, hence depends only on $|x|$.

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: Can you help me also with the third point?

Comment: @AndreaStanghellini You should ask it as a separate question